# Create Azure cloud service config from existing setup

Tags: azure

I have two Azure VM's running in a cloud service. They contains almost the same thing. Some TCP port's are also opened between them.

Is it possible to create a deploy package from this existing setup so that at a later time can deploy this setup in an easy way. I.e. I want to be able to do this:
1. Create deploy package from existing setup *
2. Delete whole existing cloud service including VM's
3. Deploy the package from step 1 and have everything created again.

*I can save one of the VM's to my Azure storage and use it as template for both of them if that is easier.

How to accomplish this if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take what you have as a template and use it to stand up multiple silos. But in IaaS, there isn't a notion of a deployment package. There's a few things you'll need to do...

1) understand how to take an existing VM and turn it into an image
2) use Powershell or another DevOps style automation suite (Chef/Puppet/etc..) to define deploy your silo.

You seem specifically interested in how to create an image so I'd recommend using the tutorial we have published on this. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image-windows-server/ This does of course presume you're running Windows Server. But a Linux version it can be found at: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/

The automation of a deployment depends on a great many things, so I'd suggest at a starting point, familiarizing yourself with the management API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I will check the links you provided. Another question, when you create VM's (IaaS) the are hosted in a Cloud Service. Can't you create a deployment package from this cloud service?

Comment: A cloud service is a container for VMs, they can be either PaaS or IaaS. PaaS deployments start with the cspkg (a package). IaaS deployments are based on provisioning VMs from image. But in both cases, you can't create a package from a running deployment.

Answer (score 0):

With the implementation of Resource Manager, you can now easily use JSON template to deploy and redeploy resources in Azure. There are also starter templates available - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/